# Distribution of users into groups taking into account requests

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function to distribute users into groups of different sizes. This function has to fill groups one by one until max size of each group is reached.
It's taking into account requests of users who want to be in a group with another user.
It's where the problem stands : when a user makes only one request, all is working well. But when this user is part of many requests, the function doesn't do what I want.

Here's my code :

I create an multidimensional array for each group with group object, max size and a counter of users added to the group.

```
foreach ($groupes as $groupe) {
    $groupesOfCompo[] = ['objet' => $groupe,
            'max' => $groupe->getNombre(),
            'nombre' => 0];
    }
```

I get all requests where a user is asking to be with another user and I add the user making the request to a group :

```
foreach ($demandes as $demande) {
        // Get groups where the user can be
        $groupes = $this->getAvailableGroupesForTutoresWithDemandes($dateDemande, $groupesOfCompo, $demande, $semestre);

        // Add tutore to group where the max size is not reached and where the counter of users is minimal
        if ($groupes) {
            $groupesOfCompo = $this->addTutoreToGroupOfMaxRemainingSpace($groupesOfCompo, $groupes, $demande->getTutoreSource());
        }
    }

private function addTutoreToGroupOfMaxRemainingSpace($groupesOfCompo, $groupes, $tutore1, $tutore2 = null) {

    // Get an array of groups counters
    $effectifs = array_column($groupes, 'nombre');
    // Get min counter
    $min = min($effectifs);
    // Get group of min counter
    $min_array = $groupes[array_search($min, $effectifs)];

    // Set group of source user to group of min counter
    $tutore1->setGroupeComposition($min_array['objet']);
    $this->em->persist($tutore1);

    // if there's a requested user in the request, set group of this user to the same group
    if ($tutore2) {
        $tutore2->setGroupeComposition($min_array['objet']);
        $this->em->persist($tutore2);
    }

    // In the initial array, find the group with min counter and increase the counter of 1 if there's not a requested user and of 2 if there's a requested user
    foreach ($groupesOfCompo as &$a) {
        if ($a['objet'] === $min_array['objet']) {
            if ($tutore2) {
                $a['nombre'] += 2;
            }
            else {
                $a['nombre']++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $groupesOfCompo;
}
```

Then, I add the requested user in the same group as the requesting user :

```
foreach ($demandes as $demande) {
        $tutore2 = $demande->getTutoreDemande();
        $tutore2->setGroupeComposition($demande->getTutoreSource()->getGroupeComposition());
        $this->em->persist($tutore2);
    }
```

There is my problem. I need to take into account users which are in multiple requests as the requesting or the requested user. And for each of these requests, add all the users involved in the same groups, updating counters accordingly.

Comment: do you prioritize requests over counter or the opposite ? Is there cases where requests might not be granted ?

Comment: Counter has the priority. But I will not have enough requests to fill a group entirely. I deal with requests before I deal with users without requests. 
I'm only getting granted requests in this function (I didn't put this piece of code in my question but it's done juste before the first loop on $demandes)